# Markdown: show html as code example without it being converted to html layout

Tags: markdown

I started this question with several examples, but since I don't know the answer, getting to posting this post was a nightmare. Every time I tried posting it, it complained about code not being properly formatted.

BUT: the question is; how to have HTML NOT properly formatted, even NOT formatted al all in a markdown environment; just as pure plain text. I simply want to say the following sentence in markdown: "Please be careful to use hello", where "hello" is inside an html element.

I want to see the html-element (Yes, you missed the div-element just now. It  is there I can assure you! I really need a method to see the div element wrapped around the "hello". And not just the hello that you can already see.)

So, is there a way to read html elements as html-elements-as-normal-plain-text in Markdown, instead of them being converted to html-layout? I need to give several simple instructions on where to place what html-elements, in a readme file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Please be careful to use <div style="display:block">hello</div>
```

Indent by four spaces (or a tab). Alternatively, some implementations allow you to place the code between three backticks "```". You can specify the language for syntax highlighting here as "`` `html".

```html
Please be careful to use <div style="display:block">hello</div>
```

Or one backtick for an inline snippet: `Please be careful to use <div style="display:block">hello</div>`.

References:

- https://www.markdownguide.org/extended-syntax/#fenced-code-blocks
- https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#precode